# connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.32.2:5432 docker-compose --env-file ./docker.env up

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to dockerize my app, so I build a Dockerfile with the script below:

```
FROM node:18.12.1 

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm i -g npm@latest

RUN npm install

# If you are building your code for production
RUN npm ci --only=production


RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "./src/index"]
```

and it runs perfectly, however, when I run the docker-compose.yml I got the following error:
`connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.32.2:5432`

here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    container_name: postgres_container
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: dev-db
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file: docker.env
    command: bash -c "npm install && npm run db:migrate && npm run user:addAdmin && npm run docker:startApp"
```

and here is the docker.env file:

```
### APP ###
PORT=3001
NODE_ENV=development

### DATABASE ###
DB_HOST=postgres
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=postgres
DB_NAME=dev-db
DB_PORT= 5432
```

what did I do wrong?

here is the full error:

```
postgres_container | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgres_container | 
postgres_container | 
postgres_container | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres_container | 
postgres_container |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgres_container | 
postgres_container | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgres_container | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
postgres_container | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgres_container | waiting for server to start....2022-12-05 02:14:11.835 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.6 (Debian 14.6-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgres_container | 2022-12-05 02:14:11.837 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_container | 2022-12-05 02:14:11.844 UTC [49] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-12-05 02:14:10 UTC
postgres_container | 2022-12-05 02:14:11.848 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_container |  done
postgres_container | server started
app_1       | /usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:131
app_1       |                 reject(new sequelizeErrors.ConnectionRefusedError(err));
app_1       |                        ^
app_1       | 
app_1       | ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.64.2:5432
app_1       |     at Client._connectionCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:131:24)
app_1       |     at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
app_1       |     at Client._handleErrorEvent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:315:19)
app_1       |     at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
app_1       |     at Socket.reportStreamError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:52:12)
app_1       |     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
app_1       |     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
app_1       |     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
app_1       |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
app_1       |   parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.64.2:5432
app_1       |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
app_1       |     errno: -111,
app_1       |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
app_1       |     syscall: 'connect',
app_1       |     address: '192.168.64.2',
app_1       |     port: 5432
app_1       |   },
app_1       |   original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.64.2:5432
app_1       |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
app_1       |     errno: -111,
app_1       |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
app_1       |     syscall: 'connect',
app_1       |     address: '192.168.64.2',
app_1       |     port: 5432
app_1       |   }
app_1       | }
app_1       | 
app_1       | Node.js v18.12.1
backend_app_1 exited with code 1
```

please note that I am using the name of the service in the docker. file, the app is not trying to connect to the localhost.
Also, I was able to connect to the docker DB using DBeaver.

the command I am using:

```
docker-compose --env-file ./docker.env up
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { errors } = require('celebrate');
const address = require('address');
const cors = require('cors');

const { logger } = require('./utils');
const config = require('./config');
const api = require('./api');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(errors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/v1', api);

const { port } = config.app;

app.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info(`server is up, http://${address.ip()}:${port}/api/v1`);
});
```

and here is the Sequelize.js:

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, literal } = require('sequelize');
const { logger } = require('../utils');
const config = require('../config');
const {
 databases: { postgres }
} = config;

const { database, username, password } = postgres;

const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, { ...postgres });

try {
 sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
   sequelize.query('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";');
   sequelize.sync();
   logger.info('Connection has been established successfully.');
 });
} catch (error) {
 logger.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
}

module.exports = { sequelize, DataTypes, literal };
```

the main .env file

```
### APP ###
PORT=3000
NODE_ENV=development
PORTAL= http://localhost:3000

### DATABASE ###
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=1324
DB_NAME=dev-db
DB_LOGGING=true
DB_PORT= 5432
```

the config.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const config = {
  app: {
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
    name: 'App_backend',
    env: process.env.NODE_ENV
  },
  portal: {
    url: process.env.PORTAL
  },
  databases: {
    postgres: {
      username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: process.env.DB_PORT,
      dialect: 'postgres',
      logging: process.env.DB_LOGGING === 'true' ? console.log : false,
      operatorsAliases: 0,
      define: {
        freezeTableName: true
      }
    }
  },
  mailSender: {
    authProvider: process.env.AUTH_PROVIDER,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    RedirectURIS: process.env.REDIRECT_URIS,
    gmailScopes: process.env.GMAIL_SCOPES,
    projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    tokenURI: process.env.TOKEN_URI,
    authURI: process.env.AUTH_URI
  },
  jwt: {
    tokenExpiration: process.env.TOKEN_EXPIRATION,
    secret: process.env.SECRET
  },
  bcrypt: {
    salt: Number(process.env.SALT)
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Why are you running `install` twice? Each of `install` and `ci` do basically the same thing (with slight differences)

Comment: @Phil Thanks for pointing this out, will modify it. 
I hope you have an answer to my main issue

Comment: What does your actual code look like? How is it using the ENV variables to connect to the DB? Do you happen to also have a `.env` file and are using `dotenv` in your Node app?

Comment: The ip address usually starts with '172.', not '192.168.'  I think we would need to see enough of your app to try it ourselves to debug further.

Comment: @Phil when I run docker-compose --env-file ./docker.env config, I got the docker.env variables not my main .env

Comment: @jjanes I will add the main index.js and Sequeilze.js on the main question, is that enough?

Comment: Please include the code in your `config.js` file and any relevant entries in your `.env` file (if you have one)

Comment: @Phil I updated it the question, you can have a look at the config and the main .env file

Comment: note that the other config variables are being added but they are not the issue.

Comment: I Just removed all docker images and run the command again I am getting the same error but with a different host 172.18.0.2:5432

Comment: @Phil I have no idea what happened but I removed all images, containers, and networks. and run the command again, it worked. 
Thank you